# Cannot understand why: ! Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to insert in a file the following diagram and keep getting an error I do not understand despite reading through tikz-cd documentation.
Any hint?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
 \tikzset{samples=500}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow[rr,''\Phi''] \arrow[d, xshift=0.7ex,''u_+'']&&b \arrow[d]\\
d  \arrow[u,xshift=-0.7ex]&&g
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `"`, not `''`

Comment: Do not understand. I use the symbol of " on my keyboard. Only after cut and paste it appeared here as a ' ' ... is it a problem of the utf8 encoding?

Comment: In the code you postet here there two of single quotes. Does your editor some text replacing automatically?!

Comment: Apparently the editor is changing it into `''` (two apostrophes), but the syntax of `tikzcd` requires the single character “double quote”.

Comment: Is there an alternative syntax avoiding the use of double quotes?

Comment: Which editor are you using, maybe there is an option to disable the replacement (when there is a replacement as suggested).

Comment: TexWorks, but I've not been able to understand if/where it is possible to disable such replacements...

Comment: TeXnicCenter also does that. I think it is related to somehow the keyboard locale settings. Try with English INTL keyboard keymapping.

Comment: For TeXworks: see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e92te.png) and set “Smart Quotes mode” to None.

Comment: @egreg Maybe it's useful if you change your comment into an answer.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331480/38074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't solve the problem with your editor, there is an alternative syntax (`\arrow[options]{direction}{labeltext}`) which avoids using double quotes, see the [`tikzcd` package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf), Section 1.4 "Alternative syntax for arrows".

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
 \tikzset{samples=500}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow{rr}{\Phi} \arrow[xshift=0.7ex]{d}{u_+} &&b \arrow[d]\\
d  \arrow[u,xshift=-0.7ex]&&g
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accept this, which solves the problem, but I am more than grateful also to egreg that spotted the very subtle problem with the editor.

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli I asked egreg to add an answer, you can change the accepting afterward.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax requires `"` like in

```
\arrow[rr,"\Phi"]
```

However, TeXworks by default enables “TeX ligatures” in the “Smart Quotes mode”, so you get `''`.

You can disable this by going to the preferences and setting the mode to “None”

[image]

but it's also possible to change the setting on the fly with the menu

[image]