# Error while running pgfplots along with babel (French)

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, babel, french

I am trying to prepare a `beamer` presentation in French (using the `babel` package). In my presentation there is a histogram generated using the `pgfplots` package. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

\usepackage{ragged2e,amsmath,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\title{Lois de probabilité}
\author{Sa\"{i}d Maanan}
\institute{ISPITSG}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi Binomiale}
\[
 P\left(X=k\right) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot q^{n-k}
\]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi Binomiale}

\begin{example}
La probabilité qu'une certaine machine valide un test de durabilité est de $3/4$. Trouvez la probabilité que 2 des 4 prochaines machines valident le test ?
\end{example}
\pause
En supposant que les tests sont indépendants et $p = 3/4$ pour chacun des 4 tests, on obtient :
\pause
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
P(X=2)&=\binom{4}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}\\
&=\left(\frac{4!}{2!2!}\right)\cdot\frac{9}{16}\cdot\frac{1}{16}\\
&=\frac{27}{128}\approx0.21
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi Binomiale}
\begin{example}
La probabilité qu'un patient se rétablisse d'une maladie sanguine rare est de 0.4. Si 15 personnes ont contracté cette maladie, quelle est la probabilité que :
\end{example}
\pause
\begin{enumerate}
\item au moins 10 survivent ?
\item 3 à 8 survivent ?
\item exactement 5 survivent ?
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi Binomiale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,15},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,15,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Loi de Poisson}
\[
P\left(X=k\right) = e^{-\lambda}\cdot\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}
\]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi Normale}
\[
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}
\]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Loi de $t$ de Student}
\[
f(t) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{v+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{v\pi} \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{v}\right)^{-\frac{v+1}{2}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But whenever I run the code I obtain this error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgfmath@local@@functions was complete.
```

So what does this error mean and how can I overcome it?

Edit: The solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331480/missing-endcsname-in-tikzcd) is not suitable for my problem.

Comment: How come the linked duplicate is not suitable? It has both an answer about using the `babel` library and an answer to switch off shorthands. That's exactly what I was using in the answer here, which you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't need babel shorthands for your presentation, you can avoid the error by switching them of with the `shorthands=off` package option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french,shorthands=off]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

\usepackage{ragged2e,amsmath,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\title{Lois de probabilité}
\author{Sa\"{i}d Maanan}
\institute{ISPITSG}
\date{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Loi Binomiale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,15},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,15,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you use shorthands elsewhere in your presentation, you can switch them off locally (in this case, also use the `fragile` frame option):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

\usepackage{ragged2e,amsmath,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\title{Lois de probabilité}
\author{Sa\"{i}d Maanan}
\institute{ISPITSG}
\date{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Loi Binomiale}
\shorthandoff{:;?!}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,15},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,15,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As a third alternative, you could load the `babel` TikZ library (you'll also need the `fragile` frame option in this case):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

\usepackage{ragged2e,amsmath,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\title{Lois de probabilité}
\author{Sa\"{i}d Maanan}
\institute{ISPITSG}
\date{}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Loi Binomiale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,15},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,15,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```